# Can we substitute this KKT condition into this optimization problem to reformulate the optimization problem?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose I have the following optimization problem

$$ \min\limits_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}} f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \tag{1} $$

It is already known that the target function $f$ is continuous and differentiable, which has a **unique** stationary point, and this stationary point is also a global minimum. However, $f$ is **not** convex. Here, I guess that $f$ is a strict quasi-convex function, and my question is based on this.

From the KKT condition, I find that the necessary condition for the optimal point is $ \mathbf x=g(\mathbf y) $.

1. Is my guess about this function correctly (just based on the properties discussed above)? If it is, then, we can use convex optimization algorithms to find a global optimal point of $f$ since $f$ is strictly [quasi-convex](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(67)90095-9).
2. Can we substitute $\mathbf x=g(\mathbf y)$ into the target function and solve the consequent optimization problem. In words, is the solution to the following optimization problem equivalent to the original optimization problem in $(1)$?

$$ \min\limits_{\mathbf{y}} f(g(\mathbf y),\mathbf{y}) $$

Any helpful comments are appreciated! ^_^

Comment: It is dangerous to confuse $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ and $f$.

Comment: Perhaps the discussions in [Sequential maximization $\max_x\max_yf(x,y)$ vs. simultaneous maximization $\max_{x,y}f(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825166/sequential-maximization-max-x-max-y-fx-y-vs-simultaneous-maximization) and [Optimal value in $\max_x\max_yf(x,y)=\max_{x,y}f(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293910/optimal-value-in-max-x-max-y-fx-y-max-x-y-fx-y/4405719#4405719) helps.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=-\cos(\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2)\,e^{-\mathbf{x}^2-\mathbf{y}^2}
$$
has a global minimum at $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}=0$ but is not strictly quasi-convex because it is not even quasi convex. For $c\in(-1,+1)$ the set
$\{f\le c\}$ is a union of sets of the form
$\{\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2<R\}\setminus\{\mathbf{x}^2+\mathbf{y}^2<r\}\,.$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Yes, the function you write is not quasi-convex, but it does not have a unique stationary point. 
The point x=y=0 is the global minimizer, but there are also other stationary points. 
In my function, the stationary point is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the optimization problem

$$ \min_{x,y} f(x,y),\quad (x,y)\in X\subset\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m \tag{1} $$

Suppose also that the function $f$ is continuous and differentiable, which has a unique stationary point, and this stationary point is also a global minimum.

Since $f$ is diferentiable you can find that $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$$ gives the necessary condition for the optimal point. Sometimes it gives you one function $  x=g( y)$. But it can gives you more the one [implicit functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

If you have only one function $x=g(y)$, you can substitute into the function and solve the problem $(1)$ as
$$ \min_{y} \phi(y),\qquad \phi(y)=f(g( y),{y}),$$ (please see [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825166/sequential-maximization-max-x-max-y-fx-y-vs-simultaneous-maximization) on math.stackexchange).

You can find more related discussions searching for "[\(\min_yf(x^*(y),y)\)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%5Cmin_yf%28x%5E%2a%28y%29,y%29%5C%29%20) " on SearchOnMath, like [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453831/optimization-of-a-function-of-two-variables.#answer-3307329) on math.stackexchange.

**Note:**

1. [**Theorem.**](https://file.scirp.org/pdf/AM_2014050811234932.pdf) Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on the open convex set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $f$ is quasiconvex on $X$ if and only if
   $$u,v\in X,\,f(u)\leq f(v)\Longrightarrow \nabla f(v)\cdot(u-v)\leq 0. $$

a) If you can verify the previous theorem then $f$ is a quasi-convex function.

b) If $f$ was a quasi-convex function. It is not clear why shoud be $\phi(y)=f(g( y),{y})$ convex.

Comment: Thanks for your time!
I understand the sequential optimization procedure now. 
So in my problem, I can substitute $x=g(y)$ into the original problem, but the subsequent problem may not be equivalent to the original one. 
This depends on my problem and the structure of $x=g(y)$.